# Sikuli and Python subprocess.call function

Tags: python, sikuli

I am trying to use the call function from the Python library inside a Sikuli script.

```
from subprocess import call

call(['notepad.exe']) 
popup("call has ended")
#do something else in the notepad here
```

The problem is that the message "call has ended" never appears until I close the notepad. I think it's related to the error code `call` sends at the end of execution.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to let you know Sikuli is actually Jython not Python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [OpenApp()](http://sikuli.org/docx/globals.html#openApp) or [run()](http://sikuli.org/docx/globals.html#run), try to use the Sikuli functions first.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to launch and immediately continue, you should use `Popen()` instead of `call()`.

You should register the subprocess objects and `poll()` time to time if they are still alive, and if not, `wait()` for them.